# Extract Hex colors from css using java

Tags: java, css, regex

I am simply trying to get all the Hex colors values form a css file.
The hex value could be #fff or #ffffff so here are the regular expressions i used for this

- `"^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$"`
- `"#([a-f0-9]{3}){1,2}/i"`
- `"^#[0-9a-zA-F]{3}"`

but not working at all.

i am expecting the result as

> #996633 #333 #ccc #969696 ....

But getting nothing, any idea where i am going wrong?

Here is the code:

```
final String HEX_PATTERN_STRING = "^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(HEX_PATTERN_STRING);
try {
        final URL CSS = new URL("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/.../bootstrap.min.css");
        URLConnection data = CSS.openConnection();
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        data.getInputStream())
        )) {
            in.lines().forEach(result::append);

            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(result);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
            }
            System.out.println("Done");
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
```

Comment: I don't see you actually associating `HEX_PATTERN_STRING` with your Marcher anywhere.

Comment: Try using `final String HEX_PATTERN_STRING = "#(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})";` and add `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(HEX_PATTERN_STRING);` before the line starting with `Matcher matcher`.

Answer (score 2):

Note your pattern contains `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string) anchors, requiring a whole string match.

You need to remove these anchors.

You cannot use regex delimiters like `/.../` either, as in Java regex, you can pass the modifiers as `(?i)` inside the pattern, or with the help of `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag (usually, with `Pattern.UNICODE_CASE`).

Also, if you do not need the numbers only, you may turn the capturing group into a non-capturing `(?:...)`.

Use

```
final String HEX_PATTERN_STRING = "#(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})";
```

Comment: my bad i just forgot to put this line `pattern = Pattern.compile(HEX_PATTERN_STRING);` in my code btw i am declaring paatern. i am updating the question

Comment: Do not forget to indicate your expected result and explain what "does not work" means.

Comment: I believe all you need is just to remove the anchors. I double checked: you  may pass the `StringBuilder` to the `matcher`, as it is converted by Java into a string internally.

Comment: @wikitor `pattern.matcher(result.toString())` is the same as `pattern.matcher(result)` i guess . but still i tried `result.toString()` and no success.

Comment: I know, I modified the answer.

Comment: oh damm you are right `^` and `$` require the whole string match i just removed them and it worked

Comment: This pattern still accepts invalid color values like #ffff or #fffffffffffffffffff

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this pattern:

```
Pattern PATTERN_HEXCOLOR = Pattern.compile(
    "#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})\\b");
```

It does accept color values like

```
#FFF
#FFFFFF
```

And ignores invalid color values like

```
#FFFF or #FFFFFFF
```

Comment: This regex will [fail here](https://regex101.com/r/JaYv3f/1). The original question does not set any condition on the context where to find the codes, the word boundary may not be the best option to use here.

Comment: But your pattern finds also color values like #ffff. I just checked that in my HTML editor APP wich highlights all the hex color values with corresponding color

Comment: In your example there are two incorrect color codes. So my pattern seems to be correct.

Comment: `#ffff` is a string containing `#fff` color code and a letter `f`

Comment: Yeah, at least the Chrome Browser does not accept CSS color codes like that.